# Java jar throttled when run by launchd?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, launchd

We have a well functioning launchd plist starting our jar file, but there's a performance issue.  We expect to send a UDP stream every 25ms.  If we run the jar manually on the command line, our output is ~25ms as expected.  However, when run via our launchd configuration, the interval is ~100ms and then jumps to ~190ns after a few minutes.

Things that have been tried...

• Setting the ProcessType

• Using the Nice key in our plist

• Allocating memory via java options

• Increasing heap size via java options

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.project</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/var/project/project.jar</string>
        <string>-server</string>
        <string>--interval</string>
        <string>25</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/project/logs/project.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/project/logs/project.stdout</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>projectuser</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/var/project</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: what is runtime jvm change in both of those launch ?

Comment: Assuming you mean which Java version `javac 1.7.0_51`

Comment: not javac, but when you launch jvm through both of them you pass some configuration or it configures it it self by default, what sort of config difference there in both execution

Comment: There are none that we set differently between either instance.

Comment: clojure does not use javac

Comment: This jar was built with Leiningen

Comment: I just mentioned because you could have one version javac in path, and another version java binary, the latter is what gets used

Comment: Your ProgramArguments array looks wrong, the first element should be only the binary, the others should each be one argument. WIth a setup like you have, the java command should not even be found(?).

Comment: The plist above was just edited to be more accurate.  However, you are correct that there are several javac's installed on this system.